# I want to convert a HTML table into a jSON array in angular 2

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

I have tried few methods but unable to get the desired output.

Here is my table like

```
<table>
   <tr> 
    <th> Name </th> 
    <th> Age </th> 
   </tr>
   <tr>  
     <td> foo </td> 
     <td> 20 </td> 
   </tr>
   <tr> 
      <td> Boo </td> 
      <td> 24 </td> 
   </tr>
</table>
```

I want the desired jSON output as follows

```
[{  
  Name: 'Foo',
  Age: 20
},{
  Name: 'Boo',
  Age: 24
}]
```

Can somebody please help?

Comment: where are you getting the data for the table from?

Comment: I'd assume you have a data source for your table. Use that data source to map to the object structure you need in JSON. Your UI should only ever display data and not be the store of it. If your front-end is the actual data source, as in, the user adds the info to the table then update the code that inserts the new rows into the table to update an array adding an object for each set of data instead and render table using that object as a data source. Then in the end, use that object to map the data into JSON.

Comment: @Farasi78 I'm importing csv/.xls sheet

Comment: @esco Depending on the data source, you may just be able to use tableData = JSON.parse(myCsvData).  If that fails, it would be necessary to look at your data source and see if you can manually shape it to something that you can then change to JSON format by iterating through it.

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can do like this :

```
const html = `<tr> 
<th> Name </th> 
<th> Age </th> 
</tr>
<tr>  
 <td> foo </td> 
 <td> 20 </td> 
</tr>
<tr> 
  <td> Boo </td> 
  <td> 24 </td> 
</tr>`;
// For plug and play sample, i just create dummy table.
const tableEl = document.createElement('table');
tableEl.innerHTML = html;


const output = [];
// Little trick to make querySelectorAll as iterable by foreach.
[].forEach.call(
    tableEl.querySelectorAll('tr'),
    //Uncomment for TypeScript strong type : (lineElement: HTMLElement) => {
    (lineElement) => {
        const rows = lineElement.querySelectorAll('td');
        if(rows.length >= 2) {
            output.push(
                {
                    name : rows[0].innerText,
                    age : rows[1].innerText,
                }
            );
        }
    });

console.log(output);
```

__ UPDATE 1 : Dynamic attribute detection from th ___

```
const html = `<tr> 
<th> Name </th> 
<th> Age </th> 
</tr>
<tr>  
 <td> foo </td> 
 <td> 20 </td> 
</tr>
<tr> 
  <td> Boo </td> 
  <td> 24 </td> 
</tr>`;
// For plug and play sample, i just create dummy table by programming way
const tableEl = document.createElement('table');
tableEl.innerHTML = html;

const output:any[] = [];
const keys: string[] = [];
// Little trick to make querySelectorAll as iterable by foreach.
[].forEach.call(
    tableEl.querySelectorAll('tr'),
    (lineElement: HTMLElement) => {
        const rows = lineElement.querySelectorAll('td,th');
        /**
         * If is th tag, we store all items to keys array.
         */
        if(rows[0].nodeName === 'TH') {
          //We replace remove all whitespace char from key.
          rows.forEach((e:HTMLElement) => keys.push(e.innerText.replace(/\s*/g,'')));
        }        
        else {
          // We craft dynamically item object.
          let item: any = {};
          keys.forEach((key, index) => {
              // We use keys array to populate it.
              item[key] = rows[index].innerHTML;
          });
          //We Store it
          output.push(item);
        }
    });

console.log(output);
```

**disclaimer :**

*This script assume you have only one `tr` with `th` inside AND is the first `tr` of your table. up to you to change this code to feet on another behaviour*

[Online sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/format-table?file=index.ts)

Comment: Idk the headers in this table as I'm importing the file. Headers are dynamic. I want the code to work in that case